# How to create reusable prepared statements in SQL Server using mssql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mssql-jdbc

I've been using prepared statements for SQL server queries but I don't think I'm using it properly. I want to be able to reuse the queries for different cases that require different parameters but I'm not sure how to go about it. So I've been creating a new function for every different case.

similar to this in java
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html

I'm using 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql
and the documentation doesn't really reuse prepared statements 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#prepared-statement

Instead of select * I want to be able to manipulate which parameters I want without creating a new function every time

```
async function SelectByStatusId(statusId) {
    const ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(connectionPool);
    ps.input('statusId', sql.Int);
    const statement = await ps.prepare(`SELECT *
                                        FROM table1 WHERE statusId = @statusId`);
    const result = await statement.execute({
        statusId: statusId
    });
    await statement.unprepare();
    return result.recordset;
}
```

When updating functions I have to define parameter types and match the body values to the parameter so I'm not sure how I can reuse statements when updating or inserting

```
async function UpdateTable1(body) {
    const ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(pools.poolDatalupa);
    ps.input('id', sql.Int);
    ps.input('name', sql.NVarChar);
    ps.input('number', sql.Float);
    const statement = await ps.prepare(`UPDATE table1
                                        SET name=@name,
                                            number=@number
                                        WHERE id = @id`);
    const result = await statement.execute({
        id: body.id,
        name: body.name,
        number: body.number
    });
    await statement.unprepare();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a prepared statement if you only execute it once?

Comment: For updating information I generally execute it multiple times with different params for the same table. I created multiple functions instead but I want to be able to reuse the same function with different defined parameters for the same table.

Comment: Title says *"...SQL Server for mssql"*, first line says "MySQL server queries". This seems contradictory. Or am I just misunderstanding?

Comment: fixed it @TylerRoper thanks